# Check if key exists in a Python dict in Jinja2 templates

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a python dictionary:

```
settings = {
   "foo" : "baz",
   "hello" : "world"
}
```

This variable `settings` is then available in the Jinja2 template.

I want to check if a key `myProperty` exists in the `settings` dict within my template, and if so take some action:

```
{% if settings.hasKey(myProperty) %}
   takeSomeAction();
{% endif %}
```

What is the equivalent of `hasKey` that I can use?

Comment: Just check: if settings[myproperty] is not None: I think this should work.

Comment: or if settings.myproperty is defined:

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Like Mihai and karelv have noted, this works:

```
{% if 'blabla' in item %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

I get a `'dict object' has no attribute 'blabla'` if I use `{% if item.blabla %}` and `item` does not contain a `blabla` key

Comment: Same for me. In my particular case I'm using Jinja2 inside Ansible.

Comment: Using jinja2 inside Ansible. Nothing helps. Both `{% if 'blabla' in item %}` and `{% if item.blabla %}` return the same `'dict object' has no attribute 'blabla'` wtf???

Comment: `argument of type 'StringField' is not iterable`. Does not work for me

Comment: Is `item` supposed to be a dictionary in this answer? That's a confusing name (an item is a key/value pair inside a dictionary). Sorry if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 42):

You can test for key definition this way:

```
{% if settings.property is defined %}

#...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This looks like the correct way of checking if a key is present in dict or not. +1

Comment: Your answer checks for object attributes, not dict keys.

Comment: @Samha' - Dict objects can be accessed via the dot operator in Jinja2. While this *appears* to be accessing a property - it's a perfectly valid solution for testing for a dict key.

Answer (score 15):

This <s>works fine</s> doesn't work in cases involving dictionaries. In those cases, please see the answer by tshalif.
Otherwise, with SaltStack (for example), you will get this error:

`Unable to manage file: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute '[attributeName]'`

if you use this approach:

`{% if settings.myProperty %}`

**note**:
Will also skip, if `settings.myProperty` exists, but is evaluated as `False` (e.g. `settings.myProperty = 0`).

Comment: Can `myProperty` be a variable in the approach above?

Comment: Yes, a key in a dictionary. Is the equivalent of ``hasKey``. And btw, hasKey is deprecated. Use ``in`` instead

Comment: when setting.myProperty exists, but it is equal to zero (integer 0) or to the boolean value False, this if test not for 'hasKey'.
This means you need:
``{% if 'myProperty' in settings %}``

Comment: this doesn't work for me (at least working with ansible). i found i needed `{% if settings.myProperty is defined %}`.

Comment: I don't get why this is accepted as answer - it throws an error if the dict is missing the key. Please correct the answer.

Comment: @MihaiZamfir There is no reason to interpret my commentary with excessive emotion. tshalif prooved the failure - and his answer seems to be the more robust one and even if "the" answer is right for a subset of use cases, it should in my opinion at least reflect that it might not fit for all use cases.

Comment: Looks like this answer fails if `settings.myProperty` is an empty dictionary/list.

Comment: Answer by @RyanTuck is the most correct and works regardless of the Boolean (True/False) status of `myProperty` :: `{% if settings.myProperty is defined %}`

Comment: fails when the key is not existent

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the style of Python, if you do a simple if statement, it will work:

```
{% if settings.foo %}
Setting Foo: {{ settings.foo }}
{% endif %}
{% if settings.bar %}
Setting Bar: {{ settings.bar }}
{% endif %}
{% if settings.hello %}
Setting Hello: {{ settings.hello }}
{% endif %}
```

Output:

```
Setting Foo: baz
Setting Hello: world
```

Cheers!